# Why is app icon too small on Microsoft Store?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-store-apps, ump

I have just submitted my first UWP app to the Microsoft Store.  Everything looks fine except the app icon shown on the store is too small.

[image]

All the icons were generated using Visual Studio's Visual Assets tab when editing the Package.appxmanifest file.  So I would assume it created things in the correct size.  I manually verified that the Package Logo images were indeed the size they asked for.

If it helps narrow down the problem, the icon for the installed app looks too small here as well.

[image]

I'm not normally a Windows developer so this is all new territory for me.  I have no idea what the issue is.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you just forgot to remove checkbox "Apply recommended padding" before generating icon assets in the Visual Studio. So, you either need to generate them again without padding, or replace some of them with manually created images.

In addition, there is an option to upload icons for the Store on submission:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/app-icons-and-logos#microsoft-store-listing-image

Comment: I noticed that checkbox but assumed the default is what most people used.  I didn't realize I should uncheck it to get a full-sized icon.  I will be submitting an update in a few days and can correct it then.  Thanks.